# needed Download link for Microsoft visual j# 2.0 redistributable package for windows 7 , 32 bit version(x86)

Tags: visualj#

Guys, I have tried a lot but I didnt find it. I will appreciate if some one could help me on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this link: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18084
not sure if it works in win 7